# Google Cloud Run with Angular Universal listening port error

Tags: angular, docker, google-cloud-run, angular-universal

I have a Angular with universal project. I'm deploying it through Google Cloud Run. I get a listening port error when loading image through EDIT & DEPLOY. It works on docker locally. Checking the logs on Google Cloud logs it cannot find the "dist/website3/server/main.js". Any ideas?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-slim
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "dist/website3/server/main.js"]
```

.dockerignore

```
node_modules
server.ts
npm-debug.log
Dockerfile*
tsconfig.*
docker-compose*
.angular
package*
karma.conf.js
.dockerignore
.git
.gitignore
README.md
LICENSE
src
.vscode
```

Comment: Angular adds a .gitignore by default. It is my assumption that Google Cloud Build firstly evaluates the .gitignore in the absence of .gcloudignore and doesn't read the .dockerignore . Default angular .gitignore includes a line blocking '/dist' folder. This blocks the file "dist/website3/server/main.js" from being uploaded. To mitigate this, add .gcloudignore file, overwriting the .gitignore.

Comment: I've also tried adding !/dist line to .dockerignore, but it still errors. I don't like duplicating the ignore files with .dockerignore and .gcloudignore . Seems clumsy. It makes me think that .dockerignore isn't read when there is a .gitignore present.

Answer (score 0):

This explains what is going on https://anandprashant.com/cloudbuild-and-dockerignore/

So I'll add .gcloudignore with

```
#!include:.dockerignore
```

This meens I don't have to duplicate content of .dockerignore in .gcloudignore and it should work like the local version. This does not work when I tested, "unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory"